# AlarmManager fires late or doesn't fire at all

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hi everybody I'm trying to learn how to use `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` in Android.
I'm having some problems with the `AlarmManager`:
I'm setting two alarms at 1 minute distance, but only one  fires and it is some minutes late (not predictable i guess).

Here's my main activity (i'm setting Alarms by tapping a button)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(Constants.EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS);
        atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),id,intent,0);
                Calendar firstLullo = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar secondLullo = Calendar.getInstance();
                firstLullo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
                firstLullo.set(Calendar.MINUTE,55);
                secondLullo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
                secondLullo.set(Calendar.MINUTE,56);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firstLullo.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
                    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,secondLullo.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
                }
                Log.d("ALARM","settato con id " + String.valueOf(id));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Receiver simply shows a Toast and makes the phone vibrate.
`Constants.EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS` is a string from a `Constants` class and it's added to the `intent-filter` of my Reveiver in the Android Manifest.

What am i missing? I googled a lot and only found that i have to use `setExact()` but no luck..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your `onReceive()`  part of your alarms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course the above code will trigger only one Alarm, because you are setting same id for both alarms.

Alarm are identified and differentiated by their id in pendingintent.

Use different id for different alarms

Update Code:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1234 ,intent,0);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firstLullo.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 5678, intent,0);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,secondLullo.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Still the same **pendingIntent**

Comment: @Strider check the id, pendingintent value is change,

Comment: how can you downvote without knowing properly, please upvote

Comment: No it's **not**, Intent to the broadcast is still the **same** so both call same broadcast, wich means that the second one will automatically cancel the first one.

Comment: Nope, i've worked adding same intents in different times.

Comment: What is the difference between different PendingIntents and pendingintent with different values.  When value is changed it becomes different only  after first alarm the value is changed so it is like different PendingIntent

Comment: You are right, **but** use different names please, only changing the **requestCode** makes it very hard to see. but I've removed my downvote, srry mate

Comment: It's ok i appreciate for removing downvote. using same name will save memory.

Comment: Although the previous answer was more complete you game me just what i needed. I didn't see that i was using the same id, i updated the code to use two `pendingIntent` with different id and now it works. The alarms are late of 45 seconds but i thing it's because i didn't set 0 seconds in the Calendar object.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @magicleon no problem, you must accept the answer that suits u best!

Answer (score 5):

The reason why only one fires is because your **canceling** your first one **always**

> **From the docs:** If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, that previous alarm will first be canceled.

To fix this, use different [PendingIntents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for both alarms.

**-** To let your receiver fire **multiple** times, reschedule it in your `onReceive()`

**Example:**
**Only if u want two receivers apart from eachother!**

```
//Declare AlarmManager
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) LayoutActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

//create new calendar instance for your first alarm
Calendar startTime= Calendar.getInstance();

//set the time of your first alarm
firstLullo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
firstLullo.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
firstLullo.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

//create a pending intent 
PendingIntent firstPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(yourActivity.this, 0, new Intent("yourFirstAlarmReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), firstPI);

//----------------------------------------------------

//create new calendar instance for your second alarm
Calendar endCalender = Calendar.getInstance();

//Set the time alarm of your second alarm
secondLullo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
secondLullo.set(Calendar.MINUTE,56);
secondLullo.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

//create a pending intent to be 
PendingIntent secondPI= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(yourActivity.this, 0, new Intent("yourSecondAlarmReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, secondLullo.getTimeInMillis(), secondPI);
```

Register alarms in **Manifest.XML**:

```
<receiver android:name="firstAlarm" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="yourFirstAlarmReceiver" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="secondAlarm" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="yourSecondAlarmReceiver" >
            </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now u can call your alarms with:

**First Alarm:**

```
public class yourFirstAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Do something when first alarm goes off

    }
}
```

**Second Alarm:**

```
public class yourSecondAlarmReceiverextends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Do something when second alarm goes off

    }
}
```

Should help u out.

Comment: What is the difference between different PendingIntents and pendingintent with different values.  When value is changed it becomes different only.

Comment: why should i create different receivers? I mean, if the pending intents are with different ids why are they considered the same? 
If i wanted to fire an alarm n-times should i create n receivers? This does not look good for me :/

Comment: No this is an **example** if you want to use multiple alarmreceivers at once, you don't need to use this if you want **one** receiver fire multiple times, than u should reschedule your alarm in your `onReceive()`. I only wrote this cause u said: `I'm setting two alarms`

Comment: sorry I explained myself bad then. Well by the way the problem was that i used the same pending intent without changing id, now it works!